# For comprehension filtering options out

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension

I have a set of items, lets call them `Effect`, and I have a list of `Cause` that have a set of `possibleEffects : Set[Effect]`

I need to iterate through the list of effects and only return the first `Cause` I find for each `Effect`. There might be overlapping causes that cause more than one of the effects, which is why the result needs to be in a set. I need this to be as fast as possible because it executes a lot of times. I have came up with the following (not sure if it is the best way, I am new to scala).

I am trying to use the `find()` method which returns an `Option[Cause]`. Is there a way to filter out the ones that return `None` (it won't happen in reality, there will always be the cause in the list, unless I have a bug), and extract it from the Some monad within the for comprehension? I can't seem to be able to use `matches` within it.

```
  val firstCauses : Set[Cause] = (for {
             effect <- effects
             possibleCause = allCauses.find(_.possibleEffects.contains(effect))
             //todo: filter out possibleCause if it is not Some(Cause), and get it out of the Some monad so that the yield takes it
           } yield possibleCause).toSet
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do set intersection?

Comment: How can I do set intersection to achieve what I need? As soon as I find one `Cause` that has an effect in the `possibleEffects` I want to stop and move to the next effect. I dont want to iterate till the end.  Unless I am misunderstanding something. In reality `possibleEffects intersects effects` will always return at least one element, that is why I am saying `None` will never happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can iterate Option in a for-comprehension, you can change "=" to "<-" and this will give you the same result as flatten

```
val firstCauses : Set[Cause] = (for {
     effect <- effects
     possibleCause <- allCauses.find(_.possibleEffects.contains(effect))
} yield possibleCause)
```

Comment: Oh, this sounds clean! What about cases where there is None, will it just get filtered out?

Comment: Yes, this will filter out None and leave values of Some

Comment: I like this implementation, You don't have intermediate collection there. This reduces the computation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to filter the ones that return `None`. You can turn a `Set[Option[T]]` into a `Set[T]` with the `flatten` method. This will get rid of the `None` for you:

```
> val s = Set(Some(1), None, Some(2), None,Some(3) )
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Option[Int]] = Set(Some(1), None, Some(2), Some(3))
> s.flatten
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

So, to be clear, you can `yield` the `Option` in your for-comprehension and just `flatten` the result.